# Funcionamiento de ->real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un login, que cuando meto usuario y  contraseña en un formulario y apreto "entrar" y tengo establecida la conexión con la base de datos, utiliza la  siguiente linea de  código:

```
$pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);
```

Estoy informándome por internet, pero no entiendo el `->real_escape_string`

**¿que significa? ¿cómo me protege de SQL-INJECTION?**

Les dejo el trozo de código completo

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['txtpass'])) 
{
    session_start();
    //variable de conexion: recibe dirección del host , usuario, contraseña y el nombre base de datos
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona") or die ("Error de conexion porque: ".$mysqli->connect_errno);
    // comprobar la conexión 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $login = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtlogin']);   
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);

    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbusuario where login='$login' and pass='$pass' and activo!=0");
    $valida=$resultado->num_rows;
    if($valida != 0)
    {
        $datosUsu = $resultado->fetch_row();
        $_SESSION['nombreusu'] = $datosUsu[3];
        $_SESSION['perfil'] = $datosUsu[4];             
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=listar.php'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 
        "<script> 
            var textnode = document.createTextNode('Usuario ó Password Incorrecto');
            document.getElementById('msg').appendChild(textnode);
        </script>";

    }   
}
```

?>

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En muchos casos `real_escape_string` no te protege de la Inyección SQL, porque hay valores de sustitución que esta función no escapa ([ver esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/5587982)).

Si te quieres proteger de la Inyección SQL, usa consultas preparadas.

Es muy simple hacerlo. Lee los comentarios en el código, donde voy explicando lo que he hecho:

```
 $login = $_POST['txtlogin'];  
 $pass  = $_POST['txtpass'];
/*
  * 1. Usamos prepare en lugar de query
  * 2. Cambiamos las variables por marcadores de posición ?
  *    Este es el núcleo del riesgo de inyección, porque las variables
  *    pueden ser concatenadas con código malicioso que se ejecutaría
  *    Nótese que he puesto las columnas explícitamente en el SELECT
  *    asumiendo que las mismas se llaman nombreusu y perfil ...
*/

$sql = "SELECT nombreusu, perfil FROM  registros where login=? and pass=? and activo!=0";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

/*
  * 3. Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
  *    Así se neutraliza la Inyección
  *    Para ello se usa un método llamado bind_param
  *    Las dos "ss" indican que hay dos columnas en la instrucción SQL de más arriba
  *    y que las mismas son del tipo String, por eso la s. 
  *    Si fueran números sería un i
  *    Luego se pasa el valor de esas variables, las cuales almacenamos desde el POST
  *    Es decir, tiene que haber tantos tipos de datos (en este caso "ss") 
  *    como columnas con marcadores de posición, 
  *    si por ejemplo la 1ª fuera String y la 2ª fuera número, entonces sería "si"
  *    y también tantas variables como columnas (dos variables en este caso)
  *    y tienen que ir en el orden en que aparecen en la consulta
*/
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $login,$pass);
$stmt->execute();

/*
  * 4. Usamos bind_result para almacenar en variables cada columna del SELECT
  *    Esto hay que hacerlo siempre ANTES de fetch...
  *    En bind_result debe habar tantas variables como columnas tenga el SELECT
  *    Nótese que store_result y num_rows ya no son necesarios, porque
  *    dado que fetch devolverá NULL si no hay datos, podemos aprovechar
  *    ese resultado para evaluar, optimizando así el código
*/

 $stmt->bind_result($nombreusu, $perfil);

if ($stmt->fetch())
{
    /* Aquí usaremos las variables de bind_result*/

    $_SESSION['nombreusu'] = $nombreusu;
    $_SESSION['perfil'] = $perfil;             
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=listar.php'>";
}
else
{
    echo 
    "<script> 
        var textnode = document.createTextNode('Usuario ó Password Incorrecto');
        document.getElementById('msg').appendChild(textnode);
    </script>";

}
```

---

P. D.: Dado que al parecer sólo se trata de una validación, he cambiado el `SELECT *` por un `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, ya que es lo más eficaz para estos fines.

Comment: Señor muchísimas gracias por su ayuda y dedicación. Estoy muy agredecido. Tengo un problema, lo que esta dentro del if me da fallos por todos los lados, no se como modificarlo para que me funcione con su excelente código. ¿Podría decirme que cambiar para que me funcione con su código porfavor? He añadido mi código completo a mi pregunta. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: @Vidal al no ver el código completo interpreté que solo querías verificar si había registros. Al editar se nota que además quieres usar algunas columnas obtenidas con el SELECT. Cuando pueda modificaré la respuesta, indicando como hacerlo. Ahora mismo estoy ocupado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!  A la espera estoy :) :)

Comment: @Vidal he actualizado la respuesta completando lo que faltaba. Prueba y comenta el resultado. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Holaaaaa gracias por todo enserio, me estas ayudando muchisimo. Me sale el siguiente error: : `Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean` ¿que puede ser?

Comment: @Vidal debe ser que escribiste algo mal en la consulta:  `SELECT nombreusu, perfil FROM  registros where login=? and pass=? and activo!=0` yo he usado como nombres de columna `nombreusu` y `perfil`... debes verificar que tus columnas se llaman así realmente, o de lo contrario, cambiarlas por tus nombres de columna reales.

Comment: funcionaaaaaaaaaaaaa! muchisimas gracias!!! :)