# como puedo usar el real_escape_string usando clases

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo una clase llamada conectar

```
class Conectar{
    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $bd="crudpoo";
    private $pass="";

    protected $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->pass, $this->bd);
        if ($this->conexion->connect_errno) {
            echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $this->conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conexion->connect_error;
        }
        $this->conexion->set_charset("utf8");//para mostrar caracteres especiales
        return $this->conexion;//retorna la conexion
    }
}
```

quiero escapar de los caracteres especiales utilizando real_escape_string, según la documentación tengo que usar el obj de la conexion para utilizar este método. Pero no me funciona o lo estoy haciendo mal, lo que tengo es un archivo aparte después de insertar los datos en un formulario por el metod post  para insertar datos:

```
require '../conexion.php';

$obj = new Conectar();

$nombre = $obj->real_escape_string($_POST["nombre"]);
$apellido = $obj->real_escape_string($_POST["apellido"]);
```

luego un error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conectar::real_escape_string().

Comment: Ya que estás migrando, te recomendaría no escapar datos y mejor usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: si no quisiera usar consultas preparadas podría simplemente sobre escribir el método  real_escape_string() en la clase Conectar?

Comment: Hola. En tu clase conectar debes implementar el método real_escape_string($param) y desde el invocar `return $this->conexion->real_escape_string($param);` Adicionalmente **el constructor no debe devolver nada** porque se usa para crear la instancia de clase. Esto: `return $this->conexion;` **no funciona**. Puedes agregar un método miembro `function getConection(){ return $this->conexion; }` si necesitas usar la conn fuera de la clase.

Comment: **Importante** considera usar sentencias preparadas como te recomienta @Triby, **escapar los datos no es seguro**

Comment: En la versión antigua de la API `mysql` la cual empezó siendo obsoleta y finalmente fue sacada del núcelo desde PHP 7+, se comprobó que el uso de `real_escape_string` no era 100% seguro. Es posible que dicho método haya sido mejorado en mysqli, pero la sombra queda ahí. Como bien dice @Triby, te recomendaría usar consultas preparadas. La seguridad es más sólida con ellas, además, optimizan las consultas a nivel de base de datos, porque hacen más que *escapar* cosas, cuando usas consultas preparadas el SGBD traza un plan de ejecución para esa consulta, y ...

Comment: ... si esa misma consulta vuelve a ejecutarse `N` veces, será mucho más rápida. Una consulta preparada es como trazar un camino al SGBD, de modo que la próxima vez él sabrá por dónde ir. Algo así como que ya no te pierdes cuando conoces una ruta, por complicada que sea :) ... También el código es más fácil de escribir, más limpio y te permite simplificar en situacioenes complejas, pasando parámetros mediante arrays y cosas así. Para más detalles sobre lo dicho consulta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151498/29967). Allí hay un enlace al pasado oscuro de `real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en el constructor devuelvas `$this->conexion`, realmente estás devolviendo una instancia de Conectar, que no extiende de *mysqli* y no dispone de los métodos propios de esa clase. La opción "fácil" es conectar por medio del constructor y devolver la conexión con otro método:

```
class Conectar{
    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $bd="crudpoo";
    private $pass="";

    protected $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->pass, $this->bd);
        if ($this->conexion->connect_errno) {
            echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $this->conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conexion->connect_error;
        }
        $this->conexion->set_charset("utf8");//para mostrar caracteres especiales
    }
    // Devolver conexión
    public function getConexion() {
        return $this->conexion;
    }
}
```

Luego, instancias la clase y obtienes la conexión:

```
require '../conexion.php';

// Instanciar y obtener conexión mysqli
$obj = new Conectar()->getConexion();

$nombre = $obj->real_escape_string($_POST["nombre"]);
$apellido = $obj->real_escape_string($_POST["apellido"]);
```

De hecho, con esto ya puedes migrar directamente a consultas preparadas, por ejemplo:

```
$obj = new Conectar()->getConexion();

// Esto es solo un ejemplo, deberías validar los datos
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
// Crear consulta en una cadena
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre = ? AND apellido = ?';
// Preparar consulta
$st = $obj->prepare($consulta);
// Enlazar parámetros
$st->bind_param('ss', $nombre, $apellido);
// Ejecutar consulta
$result = $st->execute();
// Leer resultados
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
// Mostrar en pantalla lo que se obtuvo
var_dump($row);
```

Si tienes dudas, consulta la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)